# Похоже на ошибку в описании знака

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, знаки

Не совсем понял, что за степини?

Констебль — выполнял обязанности временного модератора не менее 1 года или во время получении **степини** "зрелого" сайта.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 5):

Английский текст звучит так:

> Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation

Предлагаю такой перевод:

> Выполнял обязанности временного модератора не менее года или во время выхода сайта из «беты».

Основание для такого перевода *graduation*: это последняя стадия, в которую сайт переходит из беты. Пруф: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Site_creation_process

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, этот термин означает получение "аттестата зрелости" сайта. То есть graduation аналогично получению диплома вуза, если сравнивать с реальной жизнью.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Это да, но без объяснения никто не поймёт. А «бета» должны понять все.